# API results to HTML table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, html-table

I have been trying to get API results in a HTML table, but not able to do same. When I echo API response its coming perfectly but on rendering in HTML table it is created `<tr>` and `<td>`, showing total results and even creating paging but results are not displayed I mean it is showing blank table.

P.S. - I am trying to get results in datatables.

CODE :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#example').dataTable();
            } );
        </script>


    <!-- Bootstrap 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->

<!-- Optional theme 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


    <![endif]-->


    <style>
    /*.filterable {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.filterable .panel-heading .pull-right {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled] {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: auto;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
.filterable .filters input[disabled]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #333;
}
*/
    </style>



  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">


<?php

error_reporting(0);
    // Specify API URL
    define('HASOFFERS_API_URL', 'http://api.hasoffers.com/Apiv3/json');

    // Specify method arguments
    $args = array(
        'NetworkId' => 'abc',
        'Target' => 'Report',
        'Method' => 'getConversions',
        'NetworkToken' => 'NETkHhcasadzxcFYRnvsrtertKvh',
        'fields' => array(
            'Offer.name',
            'Stat.ad_id',
            'Stat.affiliate_id',
            'Stat.advertiser_info',
            'Stat.affiliate_info1',
            'Stat.status',
            'Stat.session_ip',
            'Stat.datetime',
            'Stat.datetime_diff'
        ),
        'filters' => array(
            'Stat.affiliate_id' => array(
                'conditional' => 'EQUAL_TO',
                'values' => '2'
            )
        ),
        'data_start' => '2015-09-01',
        'data_end' => '2015-09-01'
    );

    // Initialize cURL
    $curlHandle = curl_init();

    // Configure cURL request
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, HASOFFERS_API_URL . '?' . http_build_query($args));

    // Make sure we can access the response when we execute the call
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Execute the API call
    $jsonEncodedApiResponse = curl_exec($curlHandle);

    // Ensure HTTP call was successful
    if($jsonEncodedApiResponse === false) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            'API call failed with cURL error: ' . curl_error($curlHandle)
        );
    }

    // Clean up the resource now that we're done with cURL
    curl_close($curlHandle);

    // Decode the response from a JSON string to a PHP associative array
    $apiResponse = json_decode($jsonEncodedApiResponse, true);

    // Make sure we got back a well-formed JSON string and that there were no
    // errors when decoding it
    $jsonErrorCode = json_last_error();
    if($jsonErrorCode !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            'API response not well-formed (json error code: ' . $jsonErrorCode . ')'
        );
    }

    // Print out the response details
    if($apiResponse['response']['status'] === 1) {
        // No errors encountered
        echo 'API call successful';
        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Response Data: ' . print_r($apiResponse['response']['data'], true);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
    else {
        // An error occurred
        echo 'API call failed (' . $apiResponse['response']['errorMessage'] . ')';
        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Errors: ' . print_r($apiResponse['response']['errors'], true);
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
?>






</div>


<div class="container">
    <h3>Affiliates Details</h3>
    <p><span>Total Records:-<?php print_r($apiResponse['response']['data']['count']); ?></span></p>
    <hr>



            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="filters">
                        <th>Affiliate Id</th>
                        <th>Offer ID</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Session IP</th>
                        <th>Transaction ID</th>
                        <th>Adv info</th>
                         <th>Aff Info</th>
                         <th>Date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>


                     <?php   
                        foreach($apiResponse['response']['data']  as $x =>$x_value) {
   // echo "Affiliate ID" . $x . ", Value=" ;
    //print_r($x_value);

     foreach($x_value  as $x => $x_value) {

      $sss = $x_value['Stat.affiliate_id'];
        echo "<tr>";
        echo  "<td style='width:50px;'>".$x_value['Stat.affiliate_id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$x_value['Offer.name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$x_value['Stat.status']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$x_value['Stat.session_ip']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$x_value['Stat.ad_id']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$x_value['Stat.advertiser_info']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$x_value['Stat.affiliate_info1']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$x_value['Stat.datetime']."</td>";

        echo "</tr>";



     }


}
?>





                </tbody>
            </table>

</div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed 
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you have html code outside of body tag ? and reason being ? did you tried to validate your html code because what you doing is invalid

Comment: @NullPoiиteя : I haven't tried validating html but the same code is working with a different API. And the html code is inside body tag only.